# Proper way to work with migrations during development

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

How to properly work with migrations during development when the model is not in its final form or there are still some inconsistencies in relations?

- Should migrations be treated more as commits in version control system like git and represent even the smallest change, or what?
- Should I add new migration for each small change in my model, or should I just re-create the database and initial migration until I'm satisfied with how my model looks? I can still remove all those migrations in the end and create initial one to clean those small migrations up.
- How to properly name migrations? Most often I can't come up with a good name and I give them some meaningless names like X1, X2, X3

Similar questions:

[How to deal with database changes during development with EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197262/how-to-deal-with-database-changes-during-development-with-ef-core)

Comment: During Dev, I could usually care less about how I got to my first deployment. It is code first and my classes are source controlled. When I get to the point where I care about my test data, I introduce migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: I personally would keep it as a history. Of course you could always delete all migrations and create one that contains everything but imagine that migration after you have added 100++ tables (entity-types) and you cannot make sure your production database for instance is being updated, when you only have one migration with same name that you just always recreate.

2: Yes, you should indeed make small migrations. You can undo a migration by updating your database to a specific migration and then removing all the others before step by step. This at least works with the [package-manager-console tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell) (maybe also with dotnet tool).

For instance you have already added a migration with models that have changed you go back to the old migration by using this command:

```
Update-Database -Migration MyMigrationBeforeBadModelMigration
```

**Be aware that this might drop tables if some were added in the migration that you want to undo.**

Then remove bad migrations step by step

```
Remove-Migration // will always remove the latest migration so repeat that if you have many to remove
```

Then just create the new and proper migration and update your db.

3: Yes, give them proper names. For instance *CustomerEntityAdded* or *CustomerUniqueNameIndexAdded*.