# Unable to create SQL Table using code first approach in Azure via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I am trying to publish my database into azure using EF but am not able to see any tables after migration.

I tried below commands:

```
Add-Migration MyTables
Update-Database
```

When I check my Azure DB trough SSMS, I can see logs for all the migration in `dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory` table, but no table is getting created.

My Context Class:

```
 public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions opts) : base(opts)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

ConnectionString:

> "ConnectionString": {
>       "ExpenseApplicationDB": "Server=tcp:myserver,1432;Initial Catalog=ExpenseDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User
>   ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection
>   Timeout=30;"   }

Also in publish dialog in database section it showing 'No databases found in the project'.

If I try to achieve same thing using local DB than it's working as expected. Is there anything that am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish with .net EntityFramework, you could click the tab **Execute Code First Migration(runs on application start)**.

However, in EF core, it does not exist it. Additionally, EF does not support Automatic migrations, you may need to manually execute `Add-Migration` for adding migration files.

> Also in publish dialog in database section it showing 'No databases found in the project'.

You also could not exist the database, you could not [apply migration on publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

[image]

If you want to [apply migration at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/), you could add the following code int the `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`.

```
 using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
    }
```

For more details, you could refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243829/how-to-apply-database-code-first-migrations-in-an-azure-deployed-application/50248545#50248545).

**Note**, you need to ensure that you could connect to azure database. You could set the connection in azure to the vs local. So that you could also test with azure database in local and debug it.

Comment: "You also could not exist the database, you could not apply migration on publish" - Can you please explain this with some more details, My project type if 'Web API' instead of 'Web Application'.

Comment: According to your description, I only could guess it was an asp.net core application.And I get the same problem with you before like no database shows. So I add the code to achieve automatically migration.

Comment: You also could add the code into Startup.cs to try.

Comment: Tried myDbContext.Database.Migrate(); this in startup.cs, but still migration didn't work.

Comment: Actually, you need to add the second code fragment I provided in Configure method in Startup.cs

Comment: I tried that also, but still migration didn't worked? Any Idea on what might be the issue?

Comment: It's so disturbing. Could you have more detail info like your error message? Also have you go to "Query Editor" on portal to see if any structure have changed?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, just the migration code get's executed but table is not getting created. I also checked 'Query Editor' but not changes in that. Would be better If you can share demo working code which I can test by replacing it with my ConnectionString and than compare with my code to find what I am doing wrong. Tnx.

Comment: Finally I got the solution, I deleted my current resource which I was using for DB from Azure and created new resource by following the steps as per [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dp-DT4iZ5-8) and CF migration worked. Still I am not sure why in publish wizard it's showing 'No database found' and only way to do is via code.