# Entity Framework Core on Azure: Update-Database parameter –ConnectionString does not work

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I want to update database on Azure SQL to fit .Net Core application using Entity Framework Core migrations. The following command is advised online:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString $ConnectionString -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

However, it does not work since `Update-Database` cmdlet does not recognize parameter `–ConnectionString`. How can automate database migrations?

Comment: I think parameter should by `-Connection` not `-ConnectionString`

Comment: Supported parameters: `Update-Database [[-Migration] <String>] [-Context <String>] [-Project <String>] [-StartupProject <String>] [<CommonParameters>]`

Comment: didn't get you. You need to use `Update-Database -Connection`

Comment: `Update-Database : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Connection'.`

Comment: The question is: how can I tell to `Update-Database` which of the remote databases on Azure SQL is needed to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can automate database migrations?

**EF does not support Automatic migrations**, you may need to manually execute `Add-Migration` or `dotnet ef migrations add` for adding migration files. You could explicitly execute the command to apply the migrations, also you could apply migrations in your code.

If you want to apply migration [at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/), you could add the following code int the `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`

```
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
    }
```

For more details, you could refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243829/how-to-apply-database-code-first-migrations-in-an-azure-deployed-application/50248545#50248545).