# How to apply an EF migration to a database hosted in Azure?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core API, and I have one project in my solution named `MyProj.API` and another project named `MyProj.Data`. Both of them are Core Web app projects. Simply, `API` project includes all the controllers and other logic, whereas the `Data` project includes the models, context, repository and migrations. I have successfully hosted the app to Azure, but the point is that when publishing the `API` project, there was no option to choose the migration to apply. Though, if I run the `dotnet ef dbcontext list --json` command inside the `API` project, it successfully shows to me the context that comes from the `Data` project. Hence, I would like to learn whether there is a way to apply a migration manually to an app hosted in Azure?

Comment: You can [applying migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#applying-migrations-at-runtime), or use `Update-Database` with `-ConnectionString` parameter. For help, type `get-help Update-Database -detailed`.

Comment: @DSakura Applying migrations at runtime is interesting. If you can add it as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [applying migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#applying-migrations-at-runtime), or use `Update-Database` with `-ConnectionString` parameter in Visual Studio Package Management prompt.

For help, type `Get-Help Update-Database -detailed` in the prompt.

Comment: I do not like this answer because it lack's of a vital information: where to run this command? In Azure CLI? In VS.NET? In Debug Console in Azure SCM?

Answer (score 1):

For migration manually to .net core, you can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb#update-locally-and-redeploy) .

You may need to manually run `update-database` under Package Manager Console of VS, or you could use Powershell,
and cd to your project directory, and execute `dotnet ef database update`
to apply any pending migrations for your context to the database, then deploy your application to azure web app.

Detailed steps as below:
In your visual studio -> Package Manager Console, run the following command:

```
1. dotnet ef migrations add AddProperty
2. dotnet ef database update
```

Then re-publish the project.

Moreover, you could also follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243829/how-to-apply-database-code-first-migrations-in-an-azure-deployed-application/50248545#50248545).