# How to create Database context object in asp.net mvc identity project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a new ASP.NET project using this command

```
dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
```

It generates only Registration and Login actions. I need also create, read, update and delete actions for products model. But I could not create the DatabaseContext instance. I tried to create an object like this:

```
private ApplicationDbContext ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

It says an error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'options' of
>   'ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions)'
>   [project-name]

This is the ApplicationDbContext.cs file:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

So how to create the object of ApplicationDbContext class?

Comment: The `ApplicationDbContext` should be automatically created for `MVC` project in the `IdentityModels`

Comment: Yes. There is ApplicationDbContext. But how to create the object of this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is about creating the `object` of the `ApplicationDbContext`. The `ApplicationDbContext` class can be found in the `IdentityModels.cs` file for `MVC` project.

The automatic namespace for the classes in the `Models` folder is `YourProjectName.Models`

As to what goes for the `options` you could read it here:

[What goes into DbContextOptions when invoking a new DbContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417051/what-goes-into-dbcontextoptions-when-invoking-a-new-dbcontext)

Given your connection string name as `DefaultConnection`, it likely goes like this:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionStringSecureValue("DefaultConnection"));
```

Thus, to generate `ApplicationDbContext` object in your code, you could simply use the automatically generated namespace and generate the options to initialize the object like this:

```
using YourProjectName.Models; //initialize your .cs file with this
...
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionStringSecureValue("DefaultConnection"));
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext(options); //somewhere else in the file
```

And then use it like: `context.Users...` or `context.YourOtherTableNames.EFMethod...`