# Can I use Dependency Injection in a ViewModel for DbContext? Core2.0

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to migrate an app to Core 2.0 from a framework project. The problem I am running into Is very Similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417051/what-goes-into-dbcontextoptions-when-invoking-a-new-dbcontext), but I am trying to use DI.  I created a sample project in line with that problem but using a view model similar to how I am using it in my project. I have been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong to over a day so hopefully someone on here can help.

[In case It's helpful code on github](https://github.com/Justawebguy/gigs2)

After doing some Research, I changed the way my application was using my view model based on the comments in this post and started using the Repository Pattern. I updated the git hub example to reflect my changes in case it would help anyone.

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Gig> Gigs { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<gigs2.Models.Gig> Gig { get; set; }
}
```

GigsController.cs

```
public class GigsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Gigs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GigsViewModel vm = new GigsViewModel();
        vm.Get();
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

I am erroring out on `new GigsViewModel();` it says because I need to pass options to the ApplicationDbContext

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'options' of
>   'ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions)'

GigsViewModels.cs

```
 public class GigsViewModel
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public GigsViewModel(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        _context = context;

    }
    public List<GigViewModel> Gigs { get; set; }

    public void Get()
    {
        Gigs = _context.Gigs.Select(g => new GigViewModel {
            Id = g.Id,
            Date = g.Date,
            Time = g.Time,
            Venue = g.Venue
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.@ ";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationUserManager>();
        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationSignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.Configure<Configuration.cofAuthSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("cofAuthSettings"));


        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Comment: I would argue your `GigsViewModel` is no longer a [view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) when you ask it to look itself up on a database. In any case, `GigsViewModel` is just a class and yes you can inject a dependency with a DI container. But you are _newing_ the class yourself instead of asking the DI container for an instance. But this is moot -- Just instantiate and return the model yourself. You don't need the DI container to provide an instance for your view model class(es).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to your `GigsController` class which accepts an instance of your `GigsViewModel`. This will allow the IoC container to construct the dependency tree (instead of creating it yourself like you are doing at the moment.

Something like this should work:

```
private readonly GigsViewModel _gigsViewModel;

public GigsController(GigsViewModel gigsViewModel)
{
    _gigsViewModel = gigsViewModel;
}

// GET: Gigs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    _gigsViewModel.Get();
    return View(_gigsViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Well that got me past that but when I test, I now get this error 

 ""InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'gigs2.Models.GigsViewModels.GigsViewModel' while attempting to activate 'gigs2.Controllers.GigsController'." I think it may be related.

Comment: That is because you haven't registered the `GigsViewModel` with the IoC container (in your `startup.cs`). To solve this problem add the following line somewhere in the `ConfigureServices` method: `services.AddScoped<GigsViewModel>();` Note that you'll have to do this for all view model classes you would like the IoC container to resolve (your controllers are added automatically by the framework).

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, After doing some more research, because of your comments, I'm looking to update the app a little more to use better practices than it was using.

Comment: This is technically correct but still a horrible design. Inject the DbContect into the controller, then use a proper conversion tool to construct the ViewModel. The Get() should go.