# Initializing DBContext in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use Repository & Unit Of Work in my project.
But in ASP.NET MVC when we want use DBContext to use this code

```
MyDbContext db=new MyDbContext();
```

but in ASP.NET Core when write this code it want an argument
because use this code in `DbContext` Class

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

Error:
[image: Error]
what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What goes into DbContextOptions when invoking a new DbContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417051/what-goes-into-dbcontextoptions-when-invoking-a-new-dbcontext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be instantiating the DbContext, you should be requesting it as a constructor argument to your repository. Then your IOC container will provide the DbContext at runtime. This ensures that you can use the same DbContext throughout a given ASP.NET web request, which will prevent a host of problems you're otherwise likely to encounter.

You can see an example of a generic repository here:
http://deviq.com/repository-pattern/

You also typically don't need a separate Unit of Work in ASP.NET applications (but sometimes you do). This is because your requests should be very small and you should be able to do most of the work in a single controller or service, and then simply save through the repository. It's not that you *never* need UoW, but it's less necessary than in a thick client scenario (e.g. windows app or service).

Comment: how would you go about initilizing a DBcontext for UnitTesting or other kind of apps that are not ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 4):

You can initilize your DB context like this:

```
var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
optionBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;...");
var context = new MyDbContext(optionBuilder.Options);
```

Previous code is configuring the `options` to the connection and then creating a `MyDbContext` using those options.

If you want to use a `InMemoryDatabase` for unit testing for example you can change it to this:

```
var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("testindDB")`;
```

Comment: I have explained the code and other options in detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
```

You have not empty constructor in your `MyDbContext` class, So you should do pass parameter `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options` in constructor.

For example you can see it -> [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417051/what-goes-into-dbcontextoptions-when-invoking-a-new-dbcontext)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it: In your class UnitOfWork

```
private MyDBContext _context;

public UnitOfWork(MyDBContext context)
{
      _context = context;
}
```

In your controller:

```
private UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

public MoviesController(MyDBContext context)
{
      _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
}
```