# Entity Framework Core get context in console application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, console-application

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution with 3 projects. One class library that has DAL (.NET Standart 2.0), one AP.NET MVC Application (.NET Core 2.0) and the third Console Application (.NET Framework 4.6.1).

I have referenced DAL in both of the projects. It has implemented *Unit of Work* pattern and uses Entity Framework Core.

In ASP.NET MVC project I have configured to get context with Dependency Injection as follows

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"],
        b => {
                b.MigrationsAssembly("OpenData.Backend");
                b.CommandTimeout(4000);
            }
            );
});
```

Also the Unit of Work is configured as follows

```
// Repositories
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, HttpUnitOfWork>();
```

And in the controller I can use it like this:

```
public class TestServiceController : Controller
{

    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public TestServiceController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

What I want is to do use the same approach in Console application. Since I have not been able to put up the DI in a console application I thought I can create an instance of `UnitOfWork`

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());

_unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
```

But I get the following error on the first line of code above

> The type 'DAL.ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbContextOptionsBuilder'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DAL.ApplicationDbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

The second error

> The type 'IdentityDbContext<,,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

ApplicationDbContext is declared as follows

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        //Some configuration removed
    }
    // DbSet removed
}
```

In the ASP.NET Application it is used with ASP.Net Identity, but in the Console Application there is no need of it.

Comment: Nobody never reads exception messages. Your `ApplicationDbContext` is inherited from `IdentityDbContext`, so, as exception says, you **must** _add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'_.

Comment: @vasily is it right to use this reference `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;` in a console application?

Comment: sure, if console application is targeting .net core. Another option is to create another `ApplicationDbContext` (inherit it from EF `DbContext`) along with you original db context.

Comment: No, it is targeting Full .NET Framework. But I can try to create it with .net core since it is new project that I want to include in the solution.
My UnitOfWork takes `ApplicationDbContext` which must be of the type it currently is. I tried it but I don't wanted to make changes everywhere.

Comment: @vasily thank you! It solved my issue. I noticed another library that I use in DAL project I should add as reference in Console Application, otherwise I get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` for that library. Is this normal? Why is the use of library then... or should I try to find what I have done wrong?

Comment: all reference dependencies are should be handled by Visual Studio, so if your DAL is referenced at some library and your console refernced at DAL - VS should copy that library together with DAL to your output directory. If not - check the references of your project, clean and rebuild your solution.

Comment: @vasily it's strange but if I don't Install `Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore` I get error at runtime at line `_unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options));` saying: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore, Version=...`. So for now I will install that package.