Get appSettings in DbContext, no dependency injection, no MVC
I have a .net core 8 app.  It's a multi object layered DLL architecture. From top to bottom my architecture looks like this.

"Simple" web rest api
DLL business logic code layer
DLL Entities and TO's
DLL DbContext code layer

My Web rest API is NOT MVC, it's using the "Simple" api approach, so no dependency injection and all that... At least not that I know how to do anyway.
My DbContext codebase is in it's own separate DLL which gets compiled and deployed with the Web rest api. How do I read in the appsettings.json file so that I can store my db connection string?
In my appSettings.json I'd like to store multiple connection strings, one for each environment ( Dev, Test, Prod )...
I'd also like to store a value that indicates which environment it's running in so I can pull out the proper connection string to connect to the correct DB.
In my Web api code base this works and I will get my connection string.
string conStr = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB_CON_DEV");
But, I'm not able to find an equivalent to this approach in my codebase that uses the DbContext to get the connectionstring. I read something about a ConfigurationManager class and tried this, but it just returns null
   ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager();
   string conStr = cm.GetConnectionString("DB_CON_DEV");

Any, help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Rick

Create your DbContext via overload with DbContextOptions. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38418080/5045688

To be honest, I can't understand your structure, but if it's an out-of-box application which only require us to provide some configuration such as adding DB connection string in appsettings.json, there shall be a guidance for you which told you how to do the configuration. For DbContext, it requires a connection string so that it could connect to a database, we usually use IConfiguration to read the appsettings.json file . If this doesn't help, you might share a sample so that we could investgate, or you shall try to find the release document of your application and find out how to do it.

assuming your appsettings.json is something like
{
  "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information"
      }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=CslAupClearance;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}

then in your controller or wherever you are doing this
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

    public class MyClass{
    
            private readonly IConfiguration _config;
            
              public MyClass(IConfiguration config)
            {
                _config = config;
            }
    }

then to use it
  var connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");


Hi Bryan,
Does this imply then that I would need to get the IConfiguration object all the way back in the web api layer, and pass the configuration object down through my other object layers all the way down into the context object where I would use it?
Is that the only option?
Can I not get the IConfiguration object directly in my dbContext class?
